# Is there a strictly positive measure that is $f$-invariant?

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

A measure $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(X)$ is called strictly positive if every non-empty open subset of $X$ has strictly
positive measure. Also $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(X)$ is $f$-invariant, if for every measurable  set $A$, $\mu(f^{-1}(A))= \mu(A)$ ($f:X\to X$ is a dynamical system).

It is known that if $f:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism on compact metric space, then there is $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(X)$ such that $\mu$ is $f$-invariant  measure. Also there is a strictly positive measure on every polish space without isolated point.

In my research I work with a homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ on compact metric space without isolated point. Is there a strictly positive measure $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(X)$ such that $\mu$ is $f$-invariant measure?

Comment: do you know the proof of the existence of an $f$-invariant measure?

Comment: @mathworker21. You can find proof of it in the following link:

Comment: https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/a.j.homburg/DynSys/112-115.pdf

Comment: I know it (and actually learned it from there). I was asking if you did. I feel like it is strictly positive where it needs to be. if you don't have an answer in a couple hours, ping me

Answer (score 2):

Then the answer is **no** (if you want a finite measure; otherwise, the answer is yes: take the counting measure), not even for merely finitely additive measures.

To see this, consider the action of $\mathbf Z$ on the extended real line $[-\infty,\infty]$ by translation (or even just the one-point compactification of $\mathbf Z$). A strictly positive measure would necessarily be infinite, simply because each open interval has infinitely many disjoint translates. In fact, it would not even be locally finite: any neighbourhood of $\pm\infty$ contains infinitely many disjoint translates of every interval.

---

Note that if you flow is *minimal* (meaning, every orbit is dense), then actually every nonzero invariant measure is strictly positive (so the answer is **yes** in this case, for $\mathbf Z$-flows anyway, since invariant measures do exist). You do not even need to assume metrisability, but let us do so for simplicity. Take any ball $B$ centered at $x$ of radius $r$. Then the union of all translates of $B$ is the whole $X$: indeed, for any $y\in X$, we can find some $x'$ in the orbit of $x$ such that $d(x',y)<r$, and then $y$ is in the corresponding ball $B'$. But then by compactness, some $M<\infty$ translates of $B$ cover all of $X$. It follows that $\mu(X)\leq M\mu(B)$, whence $\mu(B)\geq \mu(X)/M>0$.

It follows that if $X$ is the finite disjoint union of its minimal subflows, then it supports a strictly positive invariant probability measure.

I suspect that as soon as you have strict containment between two closed orbits, you will have no strictly positive (finite) invariant measures.

Comment: I find this answer hard to read. i'm not sure what you're claiming at any given point nor what conclusions are being made. I would appreciate if you edited to make things clear.

Comment: @mathworker21: Basically, everything after the second paragraph was a a digression (exploring what additional hypotheses one might need to make the answer positive). I emphasised the answer and the divide.

Comment: what is $\mathcal{M}(X)$? finite measures?

Comment: @mathworker21: Why do you ask me? I considered the two options of all measures and all finite measures (countably additive, non-negative). There are other options that would make sense in general (probability, signed, complex, bounded variation, finitely additive, a combination of these), but they don't really change the answer.

Comment: come on... you said the first part was an answer to the OP's question. so you certainly understand the OP's question and thus understand what $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is.

Comment: @mathworker21: I have a couple of ideas, which I explained. The answer covers all of them, regardless. I don't understand what else you want me to say.